# Can I apply for an Australian visit visa within 7 days after getting refused once?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, australia

I have applied for an Australian visit visa under subclass 600 from Bangladesh. My daughter lives there permanently and she has sent the invitation letter. I also have provided all necessary supporting documents.

Unfortunately after lodging the visa application they sent me an email for the health examination from an email address named "Indian visit visas", which I could recognize and didn’t bother to open the mail, thinking it was something related with Indian visas, which I did not apply for. As a result, I didn’t show up within the timeframe they gave me. As a result, I found the refusal letter from the same email address for no showing up. Can I apply again anytime I want?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can apply at any time.

However, if the application asks whether you have been refused a visa before, you must now answer Yes and provide an explanation.

It is important to remember that if you consent to receiving notices from the Australian government by e-mail, [you are deemed to have received it](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/cth/consol_act/ma1958118/s494c.html) on the day they sent it.  Therefore it is your responsibility that you provide a correct e-mail address, configure spam filters so that those e-mails do not go into spam, and check your e-mail regularly.